# Why Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors

Tags: c#, get, properties, set, accessor

When we define a property like

```
    public string Name {get; set;}
```

dot net can make our properties code. but when we use

```
    public string Name {get;}
    public string Name {set;}
```

we face with

```
'Hajloo.SomeThing.PropertyName.set' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.
```

Actually why the compiler can't determine the property and make code automatically? What's the problem?

Comment: This is now supported. http://kumarvikram.com/auto-property-enhancements-in-c-6/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Because the auto-implemented properties generate their own backing store for the property values. You have no access to the internal store.

Implementing a property with

- just get : means you can only retrieve the values. You can't ever set the property value (even in the containing class)
- just set : means you can only set the values. You can't retrieve the property value.

for a normal property

```
private int _data;
public int Data{  get { return _data } };
```

Here the parent class can do the following somewhere else in the class ( which it can't with auto props)

`_data = 100;`

Note: You can define an auto-prop like this (which is how I use it the most).

```
public int Data { get; private set;}
```

This means that the property can't be set by external clients of the class. However the containing class itself can set the property multiple times via `this.Data = x;` within the class definition.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning "private set" as a middle ground solution (and it may be what the OP is actually looking for"

Answer (score 5):

If there is no setter, the property can never have anything other than the default value, so doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: You could have the property return a collection. By removing the setter you won't be able to change the type of it, but you could still add items to the collection.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger - but the point is that if there is no setter, the property will always have its default value - null in the case of a reference type such as a collection.  In this situation, there is no collection to which items can be added.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I got carried away, thinking about a property with a private setter which could then be set from e.g. within the constructor, but you're right, without any setter at all I doesn't seem to make much sense :-)

Comment: It would be possible for the language to usefully allow a syntax for `public int Foo {get;} = someFunction()` (initializing the backing store as indicated), or `public const int Foo {get = someConstant;};` (equivalent to `public int Foo {get {return someConstant;}}` except that the former would validate at compile-time that `someConstant` actually was a constant).

Comment: @supercat They have done just that for C# 6.  It is called a getter-only auto-property.

Comment: As @TysonWilliams said, C#6 lets you have `public string Name {get;}` without giving any value to it and it won't complain.

Answer (score 2):

A more modern scenario for receiving this error is building code that uses C#6 syntax using a version of VisualStudio that is less than VS 2015  (or using MsBuild that is less than 14).

In C#6.0 it is allowable to have autoProperties that do not have a setter (they are assumed to be a private set).

Try compiling with VS2015+ or msbuild 14+ .. or modify the code so that all autoProperties have a setter.

Answer (score 1):

**How to assign default value in case of null in C#**

"[Assign default value to object if value is null in c# [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471821/assign-default-value-to-object-if-value-is-null-in-c-sharp)"
This top was closed saying that it got ansewred by this one. However everything posted here does not answer that topic in my opinion, so I'm posting in here (not able to post in there) what worked for me and I was looking for:

```
decimal default_value = 0.00m;
return (decimal?)json['JSON_KEY'] ?? default_value;
```

In the example above I was trying to set a default value in case extraction of a decimal from a json is null (like we can do in kotlin or swift). Ps: This implementation works for new versions of .NET framework.