# assign default value to object if value is null in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign a default value to object only when the value is null

```
public class TempleListDetails{
    public String strTempleImage{
        get ;
        set{
            if (value == null){
                strTempleImage= "some image path";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws an error saying that

> Error 1   'Project.Entities.strTempleImage.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you must implement the `Get` also, that´s it

Comment: Also, please format your code.

Comment: You need a private backing field "strTempleImage" and name your Property "StrTempleImage" else you'll get an infinite loop (Stack Overflow)

Comment: And don't post an answer in your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must implement both, set AND get-accessors of your property.

```
public class TempleListDetails
{
    private string strTempleImage;
    public String TempleImage
    {
        get {return strTempleImage;}
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                strTempleImage= "some image path";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They close this question saying that it was already anserwred in another topic, however that topic is not necessarily the answer. This is what I was looking for when I search for the same question:

decimal default_value = 0.00m;
return (decimal?)json['JSON_KEY'] ?? default_value;

In the example above I was trying to set a default value in case extraction of a decimal from a json is null.

Answer (score 5):

Change it like this

```
private string strTempleImage; // backing field
public String StrTempleImage // note capital "S"
{
     get
     {
         return strTempleImage;
     }
```

Or, even better:

```
 get
 {
     return strTempleImage ?? "some image path";
 }
```

This will return the default if the property was never set.

Comment: I added the backing field to avoid infinite recursion

Comment: but it will check whether the field is null every time the property is accessed. it is more efficient to check once when the property is being set, and just initialize the field with the default value if necessary. I'm not sure whether the compiler optimizes things like this

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TempleListDetails {
    private string _strTemplateImage;

    public String strTempleImage {
        get
        {
            if(_strTemplateImage == null)
                return String.Empty;
            else
                return _strTemplateImage;
        }

        set 
        {
            _strTemplateImage = value ?? "some image path";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `value` in a getter