# How to set nullable getter setter and set default value if null C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have this in my code.

```
public string? additional_data { get; set; }
```

but my code is not accepting this -> ?
must be using c# version 8, but we are only required to use target framework 4

for example the expected value is below:

additional_data = null

Anyone can help with the proper code for a nullable getter setter?

Comment: If you want the variable to be a null reference, don't assign a string to it.

Comment: @Jinna please provide more info. What is what you try to achieve? You've set a default value of the property to "NULL", so if it's not set elsewhere, it will always have value of "NULL".
Also I'd suggest to follow C# naming convention & rename your property

Comment: don't use an autoproperty, use the full property with a backing field.

Comment: @MongZhu Why shouldn't an autoproperty be used?

Comment: @fredrik may be I misunderstood the question, but it seems that she wants to set a custom default value of `"NULL"` if the value is `null`

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471821/assign-default-value-to-object-if-value-is-null-in-c-sharp) might be a suited duplicate

Comment: I'm really not clear what you are asking for here. Can you give some exact expected input and outputs, preferably with a [mre]

Comment: There's no need for `string?` because `string` can already be set to null:  `public string additional_data { get; set; }` or  `public string additional_data { get; set; } = null;` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-5.0

Comment: @jinna update the question based on the comments above and let us know, so then we can reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

Few points:

- For initializing as null you should use `null` instead of `"NULL"` like this:
  `public string? additional_data { get; set; } = null;`
- No need of initializing null in your case, as the default value of `string?` is already `null`.
  So, this should be sufficient:
  `public string? additional_data { get; set; }`

Comment: This solution results in compiler warning `CS8632: The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a 'nullable' annotations context.`

Comment: That's because you have to either enable the [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) for `string?` if you're using C#8 or just upgrade to C#9

Answer (score 1):

I am only guessing what you require since your post is not very descriptive. I am assuming what you want is a default string value of "NULL" if the value is null?

```
private string _additionalData;
public string AdditionalData 
{
  get { return _addtionalData ?? "NULL"; }
  set { _additionalData = value; }
}
```