# IMapper.map() function return null values object. Automapper issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I was coding a web API, wanted to map User model to UserView model. Debugging confirms mapper.Map(user) returns null value object. mapper is an instance of IMapper Class of AutoMapper.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public UserRole? Role { get; set; }
}

public class UserView
{

    public Guid Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Email { get; }
    public UserRole? Role { get; }
}

public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
    public MappingProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserView>();
    }
}

//In startup.cs
services.AddAutoMapper();

//In user service class.
var userView = _mapper.Map<UserView>(user);
```

The output looks like this.

```
{
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "name": null,
  "email": null,
  "role": null
}
```

Comment: use .ForMember(x => x.Password, q => q.Ignore())

Comment: `UserView` has only property getters, how do you expect them to be populated.

Comment: Auto-implemented properties must define both get and set accessors. Refer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597943/3382909)

Comment: This is done with [constructor mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserView` model only has getters. If you want to keep them readonly, you can do the following

Add a constructor to UserView

```
public class UserView
{

   public Guid Id { get;  }
   public string Name{ get; }                                    
   public string Email { get;  }
   public UserRole? Role { get; }

   public UserView(Guid id, string name, string email, UserRole role)
   {
      Id = id;
      Name = name;
      Email = email;
      Role = role;
   }
}
```

Also adjust the mapping profile

```
public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
    public MappingProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserView>()
          .ConstructUsing(src => new UserView(src.Id, src.Name, src.Email, src.UserRole));
    }
}
```

The simplest way would be to add setters to all properties of `UserView`.